# Sending objects to another class's ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have a project for class where I have to send information from a driver class to a class holding an `ArrayList`, before separating them it worked fine but now I cannot figure out how to send the items to the second class, they are Driver and CardStack respectfully:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Driver{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

    CardStack cs = new CardStack(); //what to do with this?

    MathCard m1 = new MathCard(7, "+", 6);
    System.out.println(m1);
    MathCard m2 = new MathCard(18, "*", 2);
    MathCard m3 = new MathCard(112, "-", 94);
    MathCard m4 = new MathCard(2, "/", 2); 

    VocabCard vc1 = new VocabCard("Who was the first President of the United States?", "George Washington.");
    VocabCard vc2 = new VocabCard("What comes after A?", "B.");
    VocabCard vc3 = new VocabCard("What is the tune to the Alphabet Song?", "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star.");
    VocabCard vc4 = new VocabCard("Is Pluto a planet?", "Not any more.");

    cs.add( m1 );
    cs.add( m2 );
    cs.add( m3 );
    cs.add( m4 );
    cs.add( vc1 );
    cs.add( vc2 );
    cs.add( vc3 );
    cs.add( vc4 );

  }

}
```

And the CardStack class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CardStack{
  private ArrayList< FlashCard > FlashCards;
  public CardStack(){

    ArrayList< FlashCard > FlashCards = new ArrayList< FlashCard >();

    Collections.shuffle(FlashCards);
    for( FlashCard fc : FlashCards ){
        System.out.println("Test1 " + fc);
    }
 }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to learn how to pass arguments to constructor or methods.

Comment: If you're going to call an `add(...)` method on CardStack, then the class should probably have this method, no?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your problem is?

Comment: Any way that I tried to insert add(..) into the Cardstack file it gave me an error, the error I have right now is  error: cannot find symbol
                cs.add( vc3 );
                  ^
  symbol:   method add(VocabCard)
  location: variable cs of type CardStack

Comment: I already told you -- you need to give CardStack the `add(...)` method before you try to call it. Please don't ignore our comments for why make them if you're going to do this? So where is the add method in the class? It isn't there, so you will have to give it one, and in the method, add the parameter to the ArrayList.

Comment: I'm not ignoring it. I cannot figure out the right way to write that out in the code. !t was kind of glazed over in class; that is my problem.

Comment: Your question suggests that you need to study the rudiments of Java, pure and simple as this is a most basic thing. Please check out your text book or a [basic Java tutorial on methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and on [passing information into methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) (please see links), and learn. We can tell you bits and pieces, but only you yourself can build the foundation of your knowledge. There is no substitute.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the solution is to create an `add(...)` method inside of your CardStack class where in the method, add the parameter to the ArrayList. If I posted the code in this answer (which is only 3 lines of code), I'd be cheating you of the opportunity of first trying it yourself. Please check out your text book or a [basic Java tutorial on methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and on [passing information into methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) (please see links) and give it a go. You may surprise yourself with what you come up with.

In pseudocode:

```
public void add method that takes a FlashCard parameter
   add the FlashCard parameter to the FlashCards ArrayList
End of method
```